# How do I downgrade node or install a specific previous version using homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm using brew. I have node installed, using brew. I want to use an earlier version of node.

Online, I find instructions [such as](http://www.jasonfleetwoodboldt.com/writing/2014/06/25/how-to-install-old-versions-of-node-and-npm/), [for example](https://gist.github.com/mpesic/3759330):

```
cd /usr/local/Library/Formula
brew remove node --force
brew versions node
git checkout 83988e4 /usr/local/Library/Formula/node.rb
brew install node
```

The problem I have with this is that `brew` doesn't seem to have a `versions` subcommand:

```
$ brew versions node
Error: Unknown command: versions
$ brew --version
0.9.5
```

I'm new to brew. Do I need to enable the `versions` subcommand somehow? Should I use a different subcommand instead? Is there a completely different method I should try?

I'm running OS X Yosemite (10.10.1); brew 0.9.5.

Comment: Which version of node.js are you looking to get installed?

Comment: My boss tells me 10.32. I guess he means 0.10.32. I have 0.12.0 installed right now.

Comment: At this date the reader should go to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/48136

Answer (score 593):

These days if you want to install a different version of `node` you do it this way:

First search for your desired package:

```
brew search node
```

This might give you the follow results:

```
heroku/brew/heroku-node ✔
node ✔
node@10
node_exporter
nodenv
libbitcoin-node
node-build
node@12 ✔
node@14 ✔
...
```

And then install the desired version:

```
brew install node@14
```

Also remember that you can install more than 1 node package at the same time, but you cannot have them available at the same time. So if you have the latest/generic `node` package already installed you need to unlink it first:

```
brew unlink node
```

And then you can link a different version:

```
brew link node@14
```

Sometimes it might be required to link them with the `--force` and `--overwrite` options:

```
brew link --force --overwrite node@14
```

However, when new `node` version comes out and you’ll update to it by running `brew upgrade`, the link will be removed and the most recent `node` version will be linked instead. To remedy that you might consider adding your desired `node` version to `PATH` instead (and restart the shell):

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

(replace .zshrc with .bashrc or similar, depending on which `$SHELL` you use)

Answer (score 71):

**Here's step by step.**

To see your current node version

```
$ node --version
```

To see available node versions

```
$ brew search node
```

To unlink from current version

```
$ brew unlink node
```

Install any version e.g. 8

```
$ brew install node@8
```

To link installed version

```
$ brew link node@8
```

To see your current node version (again)

```
$ node --version
```

Comment: Just what I needed

Comment: How to solve this issue ? brew link node@10
Warning: node@10 is keg-only and must be linked with --force

If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: didn't work on Mac OS 10.13.5, getting error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043476/installing-particular-version-of-node-with-homebrew-is-giving-error

Comment: how can I install specific version of node, I have install node version "10.17.0" with command brew install node@10, but I need to install "10.15.3".

Comment: @codemilan, why would you need a specific minor version?

Answer (score 18):

As of [this PR to homebrew/versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/1471) and [this PR to homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/7535), the answers involving `brew tap homebrew/versions` or `*-lts` packages no longer work.

The correct answer is now:

```
brew install node@<version>
```

Where `<version>` is `0.10`, `0.12`, `4`, etc. For example, to install Node.js v6 (as of this writing, the most recent LTS version):

```
brew install node@6
```

You may need to run `brew update` prior to these commands to ensure that these new versioned formulae are available. If you have another version of the `node` formula installed, you'll also need to run `brew unlink node` first.

Comment: didn't work with Mac OS 10.13.5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043476/installing-particular-version-of-node-with-homebrew-is-giving-error

Answer (score 11):

`brew versions` has to be installed at some point after you install `brew`.

```
$ brew tap homebrew/boneyard
```

You can then use the `brew versions` command as the instructions assume.

Comment: `homebrew/boneyard` is outdated and going to be replaced with https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions as of March 2015. Install via `brew tap homebrew/versions`.

Comment: With `homebrew/versions` you will get versioned name of the package: `brew search node => leafnode  node     node010   node04 node06   node08    nodebrew ...`. So do `brew install node010` followed by `brew link --overwrite node010` to install the 0.10 version of Node.JS.

Comment: You might also need to `brew unlink node` before you `brew install node010`

Answer (score 10):

FYI, if you previously had the old version installed and haven't run `brew cleanup` (which deletes old versions), you can switch with something like `brew switch node 5.7.0`

All installed versions of node can be listed by running `brew info node` or `ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/node/`

See the brew command cheat sheet: http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/homebrew.html

Comment: Works as of 2017/12! Homebrew 1.4.0-17-gc912d26

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of answers here and other places that say to use homebrew-versions, but that gives you very limited options for which version of Node you can install.

It's much easier to use NVM and it allows you to switch between versions very easily.

```
homebrew install nvm
```

Then follow the instructions in the caveats -- `mkdir ~/.nvm` and add two lines to your `.bash_profile` and `source .bash_profile`

Then simply run `nvm install <version>` for all the versions you need. Then `nvm use <version>` to switch.

Comment: This is not the accepted answer, but it is the only one that worked for me. I wish I had tried this one the first, because I would have saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

If you need it just specifically for Node, you can use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It is very convenient if you work with Node a lot.

Comment: According to nvm docs brew and nvm are not a supported combo. I commented on this here. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3554#issuecomment-311488799 I'd be interested in hearing any war stories on this. Because on the surface I seem to have this working despite the fact it's "not supported"

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way in the NodeJS world is using the tool [n](http://npmjs.com/packages/n)

- Installation: `npm install -g n`
- Install Node 8.8.4 `n 8.8.4`
- List all your locally available node versions and chose one: `n`

It seems similar to `nvm`, but I had issues with `nvm`, and `n` worked out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without homebrew.

You can uninstall and then install the node manually.

You have to download your current running version. Here is the [list](http://nodejs.org/dist/).

Download the node-v{your-current-version-number}.tar.gz, extract it and then go to command line.

```
cd node-v{your-current-version-number}
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To uninstall it `sudo make uninstall`

Then download the version you want to install and follow same steps above.

From this [blog post](http://www.websector.de/blog/2011/12/15/quick-tip-node-how-to-downgrade-node-js-on-os-x/)

Comment: +1 this answer. FWIW, I was just able to copy the untarred ``bin/`` folder to my PATH to get this working.

Comment: Even better, you can download the .pkg file from there and double-click it to install.

Answer (score 3):

If you faced troubles with homebrew to install any version of node, you can just download .pkg file for OSX from https://nodejs.org/dist/[VERSION_YOU_NEED]. This is only helps me to reinstall node

Answer (score 1):

Let's imaging that you have 0.12.* version. To install (downgrade) 0.10 version of node throw the brew in OSX, you have to:

```
$ sudo brew tap homebrew-versions
$ brew unlink node
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/master/node010.rb
$ node -v
```

List of all node versions is [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions)

Answer (score 1):

as an example to downgrade from node@14 to node@12 using homebrew is first you need to install node@12

```
  brew install node@12
```

Then unlink node@14

```
  brew unlink node@14
```

Then link node@12

```
  brew link node@12
```

Then replace the path to bin folder

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@12/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Uninstall node@14

```
  brew uninstall node@14
```

check the node version

```
  node -v
```

Comment: Doesn't Homebrew link everything to `/opt/homebrew/bin` anyway? If not, you may also need to remove `/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin` from `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/

You can go here and install the version you need.

Before installing you might want to run `brew unlink node` to unlink the current version.

Comment: What would the advantage be of doing it this way, as opposed to using brew (as several other answers describe) or uninstalling node and then manually installing it (as @Terente-Ionut-Alexandru's answer described)?

Comment: @JohnN brew versions is deprecated as of now.Its alternatives are not very easy to understand. Also, it is kinda complex through brew to install the exact version.

Comment: @Paweł-Gościcki's answer (the highest rated, with 140 votes) seems very easy to understand, and not at all complex - which matches my recent experience with brew and different versions of formulae. My point is that your answer doesn't seem to add to anything that hasn't already been said in other answers - unless there's a reason to unlink+manually install rather than uninstall+manually install, as Terente suggested?

Comment: @JohnN That ofcourse, is easy to understand . But you will be limited by options that brew search gives. For eg. if you want node 4.4.6 exactly but the brew will only provide a node@4 option. Hence.

Comment: There are, I think, 3 decent answers to the question: (1) use brew, (2) use nvm, and (3) uninstall and manually install. What I'm trying to get you to do is explain why your answer adds to these existing answers. Why do you feel that unlinking+manually installing is preferable to the existing answers? Specifically, why do you feel that *unlinking*+manually installing is better than *uninstalling*+manually installing, as Terente's answer suggests?

Comment: I got your point. I just mentioned this answer because someone else might have been in the situation that they first installed the version through brew and might have trouble installing the correct version. As of Terente's answer, I might have overlooked it the first time because, in my experience, there has not been need to make.